# In tcsh, how can I fork multiple shell commands, wait until they all complete, and then do another command?

Tags: tcsh

I want to do the following from the tcsh command line, preferably in 1 line:

```
build_cmd1 &
build_cmd2 &
build_cmd3 &
wait until all parallel build commands finish
regression_cmd
```

That is, I want to fork off a bunch of build commands, block until they exit, and then run another command.  I want to do this from the tcsh command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

::checks with the man pages::

It looks like csh and derivatives support `wait`, so consider something like

```
% cmd1 &; cmd2 &; cmd3 &; wait; thing_to_do_after
```

or because the `&&` and `||` operators short-circuit you could use

```
% (cmd1 &; cmd2 &; cmd3 &) && thing_to_do_after
```

but *only* if you are certain of the exit state of the subshell (true means use `&&` and false means use `||`).

If you want the wait to be impervious to previously launched background tasks put it in the subshell (`()`) like this:

```
% (cmd1 &; cmd2 &; cmd3 &; wait) && thing_to_do_after
```

or

```
% (cmd1 &; cmd2 &; cmd3 &; wait; thing_to_do_after)
```

//please be aware that I haven't used tcsh in ages...

Comment: This almost works perfectly!  Could you modify your answer to have 1 slight tweak  -- combine the two answers so the combination is impervious to other background commands launched from the same shell:

  (  cmd1 & ; cmd 2 & ; cmd 3 & ; wait ) && thing_to_do_after

Also, your second answer blocks on cmd3, but not on cmd2 and cmd1.

Comment: @Ross: tweaked as requested.